# Windows key + Left/Right arrow combinations in AutoHotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to make an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that would run the following sequence once I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> -- Open an Explorer window
2. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> -- Snap to left of screen
3. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> -- Open an Explorer window
4. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> -- Snap to right of screen

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
# space::
Send #e
Send {LWin Down}{Left}{LWin Up}
Send #e
Send {LWin Down}{Right}{LWin Up}
return
```

Comment: I have some AHK scripts that do what you are trying to do. They are included in my project at http://code.google.com/p/rwintools/. Using my scripts, CTRL+WIN-ARROW will dock the current active window. SHIFT+WIN+ARROW will move the left-top corner of the current window. ALT+WIN+ARROW will move the right-bottom corner of the window. If you just want to know the implementation, you can take a look at the move-window.ahk script. Note, in Win 7, you may want to disable the default window moving hotkeys because they are conflict with my script.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine regarding which keys it sends. It doesn't work, because it sends them too fast. After the #e it takes some time to start the new window.

A simple solution would be to wait a fix amount of time. But a better approch would be to wait dynamicly for the new window. For example achiveable through the COM-Object "Shell.Application" (see answer by Grey) or AHK-Command "WinGet, , List" (see below).

Fix-Wait-Time:

```
#space::
  startExplorerAttached("Left")
  startExplorerAttached("Right")
return

startExplorerAttached(sideToAttacheTo)
  {
  Send, #e
  Sleep, 500
  Send, #{%sideToAttacheTo%}
  }
```

Dynamic:

```
#space::
  startExplorerAttached("Left")
  startExplorerAttached("Right")
return

startExplorerAttached(sideToAttacheTo)
  {
  hWnd := startExplorer()
  if ( hWnd == -1 )
    {
    Msgbox, Could not start/find new explorer window!
    return
    }

  WinActivate, ahk_id %hWnd%
  Send, #{%sideToAttacheTo%}
  }

startExplorer()
  {
  ; Starts a new Windows Explorer with the Computer-View. 
  ; Returns the handle from the new window or -1 if no new window is found

  static AFTER_START_DELAY := 150
  static AFTER_FAILED_SEARCH_DELAY := 20
  static MAX_SEARCH_ATTEMPTS := 100

  explorerWinTitle = ahk_class CabinetWClass
  WinGet, explorerWinHandlesBeforeStart, List, %explorerWinTitle%

  argToStartWithComputerView = /e`,
  Run, explorer.exe %argToStartWithComputerView%
  Sleep, %AFTER_START_DELAY%

  Loop, %MAX_SEARCH_ATTEMPTS%
    {
    WinGet, explorerWinHandlesAfterStart, List, %explorerWinTitle%
    Loop, %explorerWinHandlesAfterStart%
      {
      curAfterStartWinHandle := explorerWinHandlesAfterStart%A_Index%
      isOldWin := false
      Loop, %explorerWinHandlesBeforeStart%
        {
        curBeforeStartWinHandle := explorerWinHandlesBeforeStart%A_Index%
        if ( curBeforeStartWinHandle == curAfterStartWinHandle )
          {
          isOldWin := true
          break
          }
        }

      if ( not isOldWin )
        {
        return curAfterStartWinHandle
        }
      }

    Sleep, %AFTER_FAILED_SEARCH_DELAY%
    }

  return -1
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
oShellWindows:=(oShell:=ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")).windows

#Space:: ; win+space
   KeyWait, Space
   oShell.MinimizeAll
   Loop, 2 ; any reasonable amount
   {
      curCnt:=oShellWindows.count
      Send, {LWinDown}{vk45}{LWinUp} ; vk45 - e
      While, curCnt=oShellWindows.count
         Sleep, 500
   }
   Exit, oShell.TileVertically, curCnt:=""
```